# Summarizing outcomes by groups in R

Tags: r, sum

The following code works....

```
sum(  (WASDATj$HCNT == 1 | WASDATj$HCNT == -1 |  WASDATj$HCNT == 0  ) & WASDATj$Region=='United States' 
    & WASDATj$Unit=='Million Bushels' 
    & WASDATj$Commodity=='Soybeans'
    &  WASDATj$Attribute == 'Production' 
    &  WASDATj$Fdex.x == 10
    ,na.rm=TRUE  
    )
```

It counts the number of observations where `HCNT` takes a value of `-1,1,0`
it provides a single number for this category.
The variable `WASDATj$Fdex.x` takes a value from 1-20.

How can I generalize this to count the number of observations that take a value `-1,1,0` for each of the values of `Fdex.x` (so provide me 20 sums for `Fdex.x` from 1-20)?  I did look for an answer, but I'm such a novice I may have missed what is an obvious answer....

Comment: Hi Its-ame Mari! Welcome to SO! Very likely we can help and improve what you have so far. To help further, please edit your question with example data from `WASDATj` using `dput(head(WASDATj))` and include what your final result should like (perhaps a data frame with 2 columns, 1st column Fdex.x value 1-20 and 2nd column with the sum). Is the `na.rm` for `NA` values anywhere in your data or just intended for one column? Finally, please see [how to make a great reproducible example in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Simply extend your `sum` of a boolean vector to `aggregate` function using `length` which is essentially a count aggregation and analogous to your `sum` of `TRUE`:

```
agg_df <- aggregate(cbind(Count=HCNT) ~ Fdex.x, 
                    data=WASDATj[WASDATj$HCNT %in% c(1,-1, 0) &
                                 WASDATj$Region=='United States' & 
                                 WASDATj$Unit=='Million Bushels' &
                                 WASDATj$Commodity=='Soybeans' &
                                 WASDATj$Attribute=='Production', ],
                    FUN=length)
```

Result should be a data frame of 20 rows by two columns for each distinct `Fdex.x` value and corresponding count.

And if needed, you can extend grouping for other counts by adjusting formula and data filter:

```
agg_df <- aggregate(cbind(Count=HCNT) ~ Fdex.x + Region + Unit + Commodity + Attribute, 
                    data=WASDATj[WASDATj$HCNT %in% c(1,-1, 0), ],
                    FUN=length)
```